# ElasticSearch starts with query for autocomplete feature

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I want to build an autocomplete feature using ElasticSearch and C#. But I am not getting the desired result. For demo purpose this is what I have done.

1) Created index called "names":

```
PUT names?pretty
```

2) Added 20 entries using POST command:

```
POST names/_doc/1
{
  "name" : "John Smith"
}
```

3) List of Names:

```
[ "John Smith", "John Smitha", "John Smithb", "John Smithc", "John Smithd", "John Smithe", "John Smithf",
  "John Smithg", "John Smithh", "John Smithi", "Smith John", "Smitha John", "Smithb John", "Smithc John",
  "Smithd John", "Smithe John", "Smithf John", "Smithg John", "Smithh John", "Smithi John",]
```

4) When I run a prefix query:

```
GET names/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Smith"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to get back `"Smith John", "Smitha John"`... But I am getting back `"John Smith", "John Smitha"`...

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change and where?

Comment: Please check my answer and it was a better idea to provide `mapping` of index to troubleshoot these issues.

Comment: Can you try to run your query on `name.keyword` instead of `name`. Since you haven't defined a specific defined, that might do the trick. If you want to go further with autocompletion, using the `prefix` query is only the beginning, there's much more you can do.

Comment: @Val Changing to `name.keyword` did the trick. Can you please explain why or provide a link to learn more about it? Thanks!

Comment: I provided more info in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your `name` field as `text` field which by default uses the [standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) analyzer and converts the tokens to lowercase. You can test this by using the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) of ES.

### Tokens example for keyword analyzer

URL :- http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{index}}/_analyze

```
{
  "text": "John Smith",
  "analyzer" : "keyword"
}
```

The output of above API

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "John Smith",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that it's not breaking the `text` and storing it as it is as explained in [official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html).

### Tokens with standard analyzer

```
{
  "text": "Smith John",
  "analyzer" : "standard"
}
```

The output of the above API:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "john",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "smith",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when prefix query isn't analyzed and send it as it is to ES, hence `Smith` notice with Capital `S` would be sent to ES for token matching, now with updated mapping, only documents starting with `Smith` will have that prefix and only these will come in search results.

### Mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search Query

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "name": {
                "value": "Smith"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** :- ** Updated the setting based on the OP comments and based on above setting and search query, it gets only the results starts with `Smith` as shown in below output

```
{
  "took": 811,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 5,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "59977669",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Smith John"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "59977669",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Smithb John"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "59977669",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "8",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Smithc John"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "59977669",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "9",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Smithd John"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "59977669",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "10",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Smithe John"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I dropped old index, created new index with the settings and mappings you have provided, inserted the data and ran a query. I am still getting "John Smith" as a first result and not "Smith John".

Old Mappings:
`{
  "names" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @NishithShah, I updated my answer based on your comments and also added more detailed explaination , please go through it and let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your prefix query on the `name.keyword` field and not on the `name` field.

```
GET names/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name.keyword": {
        "value": "Smith"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The reason is that the `name.keyword` field is of [type `keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) and is not analyzed (i.e. one token `John Smith` is indexed) and hence you can perform and exact match query on it. The `name` field is of [type `text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) and is analyzed (i.e. two tokens `john` and `smith` are indexed) and hence your exact match (or prefix match) query doesn't work.

You can read more about it here

Comment: yes it worked, but I ended up using Completion Suggester. Thanks for your help.